# Symfony Built-in server terminated unexpectedly

Tags: php, symfony

I am having a very hard problem to solve, which is that my symfony application server terminates and never loads anything. The message is giving after running the: `php bin/console server:run` and then load the site in the browser. The browser starts loading the site but after a few minutes it throws this message in the console (not in the web browser): `[ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly. Run the command again with -v option for more details.`.

I have tried to solve this problem in many ways:

1. Changed my OS to Windows (I am using Ubuntu 16.04). This did not work, the application just throw a blank page in the browser with not even one error.
2. Cleared cache.
3. Changed default port.

Please if any person has been involved in this situation and has left alive from it, help me out, I will appreciate it a lot...

Comment: have you tried `Run the command again with -v option for more details.` ?

Comment: Hi!, how can I execute that command? writing the -v at the end?, I have tried but I might have some kind of syntax error

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Where can I find the server logs? I am a noob in symfony, actually I am just setting up the stack in my pc

Comment: @JesusSoto `php bin/console server:run -v` or even `php bin/console -v server:run`

Comment: Thank you @hassan I am running the server with -v options, but the only additional thing it says is: RES 139 Command did not run successfully

Comment: can you trace the errors in that commands?

Comment: How can I trace the errors? Where can I find an error log of symfony? I mean symfony should throw it in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem. I upgraded from php 7.0 to php 7.1, it is a bug of php I guess, I can't have any certain conclusion about what the problem was, but this solved it.